# How do I create Vim syntax highlighting rules that are common to all filetypes?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, highlight, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to highlight trailing whitespace in vim, regardless of filetype.

I'm able to do it on a per-filetype basis. For example, for HTML:

---

*~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim*

```
color html
```

---

*~/.vim/syntax/html.vim*

```
syn match TrailingSpace display excludenl /\s\+$/
```

---

*~/.vim/colors/html.vim*

```
hi TrailingSpace ctermbg=52
```

---

*~/.vimrc*

```
syntax on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```

---

These settings make it so that trailing spaces at the end of a line are highlighted with a red background. (They also override all of vim's built-in HTML syntax and highlighting, but I'm fine with that.)

The trouble is that if I want to do the same for JavaScript, for instance, I have to add the same `syn` and `hi` line to that file, and so on for every other filetype.

What I would like to be able to do is put *these two lines*:

```
syn match TrailingSpace display excludenl /\s\+$/
hi TrailingSpace ctermbg=52
```

in just one place in my `.vim` directory structure and have them apply to all filetypes.

I've tried adding them to `.vimrc` and I've tried adding them to `~/.vim/plugin/settings.vim` and that didn't work either.

Other `hi` lines I've added to `~/.vim/plugin/settings.vim` worked universally, but only for built-in vim syntax items, e.g. `MatchParen` and `IncSearch`.

Is there any file where I could add just the two lines above and it would work? I can split them up and put them in separate files, but ideally, I wouldn't have to add anything anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my own solution to the exact same issue:

```
autocmd BufEnter,WinEnter * call matchadd("Error", "\\s\\+$", -1)
```

I started with the same "syntax" method but I ended up facing the same issues that you are facing right now with no simple solution.

And here is what it looks like:

[image: matchadd()]

Comment: You could simply put this line in your `~/.vimrc`.