# Why don't the syntax-match plus highlight commands work?

Tags: vim

I want to get Vim (MacVim for now) to highlight non-ASCII characters.  As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988346/151007) I added these two lines to my vimrc:

```
syntax match nonascii "[^\x00-\x7F]"
highlight nonascii guifg=#ffffff guibg=#ff0000
" highlight link nonascii ErrorMsg     (this didn't work either)
```

And I pasted some text containing a right single quote (hex 2019) into an HTML file.  Vim didn't highlight it.

But when I replaced the two lines above with the following, it worked:

```
syn match ErrorMsg /[^\x00-\x7F]/
```

Why didn't the first version work?

EDIT: further investigation shows neither version works when I open vim with my file.  But both work if I execute them by hand when vim is already open.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution only works for the GUI (`gvim`); if you're using Vim from a terminal, add `ctermbg` and/or `ctermfb`, for example:

```
highlight nonascii guifg=#ffffff guibg=#ff0000 ctermbg=red
```

Comment: Thanks though I forgot to mention this is in a GUI (MacVim).  I'll update my question.

Comment: @AndyStewart Right ... Your original commands seem to work in gVim (Linux) btw, so it could be a MacVim-specific thing?)

Comment: Hmm, it turns out neither works at start-up, but both work when I execute manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my second version working by prepending `autocmd BufEnter *`:

```
autocmd BufEnter * syn match ErrorMsg /[\x00-\x7F]/
```

The idea came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951793/151007) about non-filetype-specific syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me too to custom highlight a specific regex pattern, though I wish there was a cleaner solution.